# Condition to check URL query

Tags: python, web2py

How would I create an if...else condition to check the following:

```
if the URL ends with this /default/add?a=1&b=1
    compute something
else the URL ending with this /default/add/1/1
    compute this
```

So, far my function looks like this. I'm able to compute the first condition, but I don't think it's correct.

```
def add():
if URL(scheme=True,args=[add]):
    a1 = int(request.vars.a)
    b1 = int(request.vars.b)
    return a1+b1
else:
    a2 = int(request.args[0])
    b2 = int(request.args[1])
    return a2+b2
```

When I try to test it against /default/add/1/1, I get the following error:

```
a1 = int(request.vars.a)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2):

for `/default/add?a=1&b=1` use:

```
a1 = int(request.vars['a'])
b1 = int(request.vars['b'])
```

and for `/default/add/1/1` use:

```
a2, b2 = map(int, tuple(request.args))
```

Answer (score 0):

request.vars is a dict, so syntax should probably be:

```
a1 = int(request.vars['a'])
```

Edit: user1434070 beat me to it -- sorry for the dupe

Answer (score 0):

`URL(scheme=True,args=[add])` generates a URL -- it does not check the URL of the current request. Instead, you want:

```
    if 'a' in request.vars and 'b' in request.vars:
```